# Hartshorne proposition II.6.9, degree of pull back map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* and got struck in understanding the proof of proposition 6.9 in chapter II (page 138) where it is proved that for a finite morphism $f: X \to Y$ between non-singular curves, $\deg  f^* Q = \deg f$ for a closed point $Q$ of $Y$. Here $A^{\prime}$ is the free $\mathcal{O}_Q$-module of rank $r=[K(X):K(Y)]$. Fibres of $Q$ are $P_1, P_2,..,P_n$ that corresponds to maximal ideals $m_1,..,m_n$. Here I don't understand the following:

1. Why are the ideals $tA^{\prime}_{m_i} \cap A^{\prime}$ are comaximal so that we can apply Chinese remainder theorem?
2. Why is $\cap(tA^{\prime}_{m_i} \cap A^{\prime})= tA^{\prime}$?
3. Why $A^{\prime}/(tA^{\prime}_{m_i} \cap A^{\prime}) \cong A^{\prime}_{m_i}/tA^{\prime}_{m_i}$?

Thanks in advance. Any help or suggestion in understanding this proof is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A'$ is a Dedekind domain.

1. $tA'_{m_i}\cap A'$ is some power of $m_i$ (in fact it is $m_i^{e_i}$ where $e_i$ is the ramification index) and as the $m_i$ are distinct maximal ideals this implies that these powers are comaximal.
2. $\bigcap (tA'_{m_i}\cap A')=(\bigcap tA'_{m_i})\cap A'=(t\bigcap A'_{m_i})\cap A'=tA'\cap A'=tA'$ (any integral domain is the intersection of its localization at prime ideals where we may omit the zero ideal if the ring is not a field.)
3. $tA'_{m_i}=m_i^{e_i}A_{m_i}'$ for some $e_i$. As $m_i$ is maximal we have $m_i^{e_i}A_{m_i}'\cap A'=m_i^{e_i}$, thus $$A'/(tA_{m_i}'\cap A')=A'/m_i^{e_i}=(A'/m_i^{e_i})_{m_i}\cong A_{m_i}'/m_i^{e_i}A_{m_i}'=A_{m_i}'/tA_{m_i}'$$